# How to fix choice prompt buttons and http 404 in direct line channel? (bot framework v4, direct line API 3)

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have deployed my bot to a website by creating a direct line channel in Azure portal. In my bot I have several choice prompts for confirmation throughout the dialog which works smoothly for the most part. The issue is that for one choice prompt in particular, the buttons are sometimes not rendered. In the Azure portal application insights I see that there's a GET request that fails with response code 404, and I assume that it is related to this issue. Why does this happen and how can I solve this issue?

This is how it should appear constantly vs how it randomly appears:

[image][image]

From application insights:

[image]

**EDIT:**

The chat bot is embedded to my website using direct line channel in Azure and direct line API 3. The website is developed in Drupal, which *could* be relevant for this problem...
Sometimes the "yes/no" buttons shows as a flash.

**Code for this choice prompt**:

```html
private async Task<DialogTurnResult>ConfirmationStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{ 
    var response = (string)stepContext.Result;                 
    stepContext.Values["phone"] = response; 
    var opts = new PromptOptions 
    { 
        Prompt = MessageFactory.Text($"Du har gitt
        oss følgende opplysninger:\n\nTelefon: {response}\n\nEr dette korrekt?"), 
        RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Vennligst velg ett av alternativene."), 
        Choices = new List<Choice>(), 
    }; 
     
    opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = " Ja", Synonyms = new List<string> { "Ja", "ja" } });                 
    opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = " Nei", Synonyms = new List<string> { "Nei", "nei" } }); 
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), opts, cancellationToken); 
} 

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ConfirmationValidationStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{ 
    var response = ((FoundChoice)stepContext.Result).Value.ToLowerInvariant();     
    if (response == " ja") 
    { 
        var opts = new PromptOptions() 
        { 
            Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Dine opplysninger vil lagres og brukes i henhold til lover og forskrifter om personvern (GDPR). Samtykker du til at vi lagrer dine opplysninger?"), 
            RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Vennligst velg ett av alternativene."),
            Choices = new List<Choice>(), 
        }; 
       opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = " Ja", Synonyms = new List<string> { "Ja", "ja" } });                    
       opts.Choices.Add(new Choice() { Value = " Nei", Synonyms = new List<string> { "Nei", "nei" } });
       return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(ChoicePrompt), opts, cancellationToken); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("La oss begynne forfra så du kan fylle ut opplysningene på nytt."), cancellationToken); 
        return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(nameof(PhoneDialog), null, cancellationToken); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Which SDK and version are you running? And, can you post your code that includes your various choice prompts?

Comment: I use SDK version 4 for .NET (build type is .Net Core 2.1) I have multiple choice prompts in multiple dialogs, but I will edit the post to include the code for the choice prompt which fails to render on my website.

Comment: Are any errors emitted when you step thru?

Comment: The code itself works fine in the bot framework emulator - No errors are emitted. However, the choice prompt of interest doesn't render (sometimes) both in the webchat in azure portal and using the direct line channel, which makes me think that it is not the web site platform(drupal) that is the problem. It is only the 404 Get request fail which appear in azure that I can get a hold of, but I am not certain that it is related to this problem at all. No errors are displayed using developer tool in chrome.

Comment: As mentioned, the buttons sometimes appear as a flash, i.e. super quickly before or after the prompt itself. I could perhaps try to set a delay? But it does not necessarily fix the rendering issue, but the order...

Comment: Can you post the code for the step that immediately precedes it? I'm curious how / what the step returns when it finishes and moves on to the next step (that isn't rendering).

Comment: I have added the next step in the post.

Comment: i'm curious, could you try your code without the emojis keeping just the text (i.e. "Ja" and "Nei")? I would be surprised if the emojis are causing the problem, but stranger things have happened.

Comment: @StevenKanberg It did not work removing the emojis. I still experience the same issue.

Comment: @Lanna - Hi Please let me know how you fixed this issue i am also facing the same issue